# Ending of The Adventures of Hutch the Honeybee

Tags: hutch-the-honeybee

[The Adventures of Hutch the Honeybee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Hutch_the_Honeybee) was aired when I was a child, but I never know its ending. [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3858/Konchuu_Monogatari_Minashigo_Hutch) said that it was aired in Japan from 1970 to 1971, but it was aired in my country around the end of the '90s or early 2000s I think.

So, how did the anime end? Did he reunite with his mom? Does someone know?

Comment: that is the remake, in the original serie since 1970 to 1971 the end was thata it´s mother is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Italian wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_avventure_dell%27Ape_Mag%C3%A0) a synopsis of the series is present, here is the translation of the ending:

> [...] During his journey Hutch will meet another bee called Aya, who will decide to take part in his search. Eventually Hutch, after many hardships, will find his mother and he will save her from a certain death. He will also find out that Aya is actually his sister, who managed to survive to the wasps' attack at the beginning of the story. Leaving finally his loneliness, Hutch will find his family and will put his efforts in rebuilding his kingdom, trying to make it even nicer and more peaceful than the one it was once.

There is also a sequel, called [New Honeybee Hutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Honeybee_Hutch)

> The sequel starts some time after the events of the first series, as Hutch and his sister, Aya, lose their mother, the Queen Bee, after an attack of the Wasps which destroys their Kingdom. Together, they embark on a long and dangerous journey to find a place called the Beautiful Hill, on which they would rebuild their kingdom, and Aya would become the Queen. Tenten, a ladybug, befriends Hutch and Aya and joins them on their journey, as he searches for his missing father. At the same time they have to confront Apachi, a wasp who seeks revenge against Hutch, believing that he killed his father.

[image]